Introduction to Proper forcing
I’m trying to understand how proper forcing was introduced and the feeling of the model theoretic equivalence
Could you please recommend a great introductory text? I have read the Jech’s Multiple Forcing and “Taste of proper forcing” by Goldstern, but I still can’t feel where the properness comes from
Thanks for your help

I briefly touched on properness in my lecture notes. Have you had a look?

Perhaps Section 5 of Justin Moore's ICM paper has what you want?  https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~justin/Ftp/ICM.pdf

@AsafKaragila I will do it, thank you!

@ChrisEagle Thank you! I'll take a look

@AsafKaragila Do you mean these notes https://karagila.org/files/Forcing-2023.pdf ?

Yes, these notes.

Have you taken a look at Shelah's book? He explains well the motivation for the definition.
Here is a very condensed story about it: in many cases, you want a result that says that there are no subsets of $\omega_1$ with some property. Given one of these sets, you may have a reasonable way to design a forcing notion that ensures the set no longer has the property in the extension. So you just need to find a way to iterate these posets, while carrying out some reasonable bookkeeping so that all sets with the property, not just those in the ground model, but those that appear along the way during the iteration, are taken care of. Part of achieving this is ensuring that you preserve $\omega_1$ along the way (and at the end!), because otherwise you are not really addressing the problem.
The goal is then to have a class of forcing posets that preserve $\omega_1$ under some kind of iteration, but it is not quite obvious how to define such a class that is not too restrictive. I mean, ccc forcing and $\omega_1$-closed forcing achieve this, but the goal is to have a bigger class, because there are many problems for which these two classes do not seem enough, they impose too many technical restrictions that seem to conflict with what one would like to do in an iteration to solve some of these problems.
An initial observation is that simply taking the class of posets that preserve $\omega_1$ is definitely not enough: there is a countable iteration such that each step preserves $\omega_1$, but no matter what kind of limit we consider, $\omega_1$ is collapsed at the end. It may be useful to sketch the idea: partition $\omega_1$ into countably many stationary pieces $\langle S_n:n<\omega\rangle$. Given a stationary subset $S$ of $\omega_1$, Jensen found a forcing notion $\mathbb P_S$ that adds a subset of $S$ that is club in $\omega_1$ while adding no new countable subsets of $\omega_1$ (so, in particular, preserving $\omega_1$). This poset has the property that if $T$ is a stationary subset of $S$, then $T$ is still stationary in the extension. We can then consider the iteration that at stage $n$ uses the Jensen poset to adds a club subset of the complement of $\bigcup_{i\le n}S_i$. Each stage of this iteration preserves $\omega_1$, but the whole iteration, no matter what kind of limit we consider, collapses $\omega_1$ (because the iteration adds a countable sequence of clubs with empty intersection).
In order to address this and similar examples, it seems reasonable to look at a class of posets that not only preserve $\omega_1$, but in fact preserve the stationarity of subsets of $\omega_1$. It turns out that a lot can be said about this class (the class of all forcing notions that preserve stationary subsets of $\omega_1$), but its study is subtle enough that a simpler class (that of proper posets) was first considered.
The problem is that, again, we can define an iteration where each stage preserves stationary subsets of $\omega_1$, but any way of taking the limit collapses $\omega_1$. The example I know, due to Shelah, is more technical than the one above; it consists on generically adding, one by one, an infinite $<_{\mathrm{NS}_{\omega_1}}$-descending sequence of functions $f\!:\omega_1\to\omega_1$. Here, $f<_{\mathrm{NS}_{\omega_1}}g$ means that $\{\alpha<\omega_1: f(\alpha)< g(\alpha)\}$ contains a club, and the point is that $<_{\mathrm{NS}_{\omega_1}}$ is well-founded.
The posets in this example not only preserve stationarity of subsets of $\omega_1$ but of all uncountable regular cardinals $\kappa$. To address this new obstacle, Shelah decided to consider the more restrictive class of posets that preserve, not just this stationarity, but in fact that of subsets of $[\kappa]^{\le\aleph_0}$. This was the key move, and the corresponding posets are precisely the proper forcing notions. Shelah noticed that ccc forcing can be characterized in a "model-theoretic" way, and this suggested the definition. He also saw how, rather than looking at finite supports (as with ccc forcing), the class can be iterated via the somewhat more involved notion of countable support.
In MR1623206 (98m:03002), zbM0889.03041,

Shelah, Saharon. "Proper and improper forcing".
Second edition. Perspectives in Mathematical Logic. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1998. xlviii+1020 pp. ISBN: 3-540-51700-6

properness is introduced in Chapter III, the beginning of which is devoted to motivation. Shelah's book is huge, and some of it is very technical, but there are many examples presented there (not just in Chapter III) in good degree of detail. In particular, the second example above is described in section 5 of chapter VII.
Another good place to get acquainted with the relevant notion of stationarity and its relation to properness is Baumgartner's article, MR0776640 (86g:03084), zbM0556.03040

Baumgartner, James E. Applications of the proper forcing axiom, in "Handbook of set-theoretic topology", 913–959, North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1984,

which I definitely recommend as Baumgartner is an excellent expositor.

An endnote: above, I said that it is worth studying the class of posets that preserve stationary subsets of $\omega_1$, but that their study is more subtle. If you are interested, look at the class of semi-proper forcing posets, at the notion of RCS (revised countable support) iterations, and at Martin's maximum $\mathsf{MM}$.

What a wonderful answer!!!

Thank you, Asaf.

Wow, thank you so much for your answer, I appreciate the time and effort you put on it! I was a little scared to look at Shelah’s book because it seem very technical, but it looks like a very great place to start
